# Please explain Wx::Thread example

Tags: multithreading, perl, wxperl

The [documentation for Wx::Thread](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Wx/lib/Wx/Thread.pod) includes a small but instructive example of how to post an event from a child thread to a window in the main or parent thread.

What I cannot understand is how it can possibly be valid to refer to the file-scoped lexical variable `$frame` from the child thread as illustrated.  The sequence of events is as follows: 1) start child thread; 2) initialize `$frame`; 3) *...time passes...*; 4) child thread posts event to `$frame`.

I had thought that all non-shared variables get cloned when a thread starts.  How can `$frame` be anything but `undef` in the child thread?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that makes no sense. The thread's copy of $frame will be undef since $frame was populated after it was cloned by thread-creation.

Comment: Are they relying on the entry to the function taking longer than the variable declaration?

Comment: That won't work unless it's shared. `perl` clones it's entire variable space at thread instantiation, unless it's explicitly shared.